# Is it possible to get varchar's unique number value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sample:

```
select 'test1' 
union all
select 'test2'
```

Expected output:

```
value
5XXXXXXX94
5XXXXXXXX6
```

What I have tried:

I tried using md5 to do it, but it's not number type and it's possible duplicate.

```
select md5('test1')
union all
select md5('test2')
```

[image]

[Postgres 11 Demo Link | db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=edf934f22a3b118aac3b1bd163a8c87f)

Comment: @Akina it's good idea, can you answer below? if there not anothor answer I'll mark it answer.

Comment: Converted to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table which will hold the relation between a string and a code. Create function which accepts the string, searches it in the table, if not found then generates and inserts unique random (or next using some generator) code, and then returns the code (found or generated).

Or create a function which generates some hand-made "hash". For example, it may get code of each char in a string and perform some deterministic calculations with it. In this case you do not need in relational table. Or you may use CRC32 converting it to decimal form (just get up to 10 digits).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit :** I've change the function [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=adbca7f6ba9878ea29a381ffdbec4f6f)

```
with x as (
select 'test1' as word
union all
select 'test2'
union all
select 'test2'
union all
select 'test2'
union all
select 'test1'
union all
select 'test1'
)
select
    x.word,
    (select ('x'||substr(md5(x.word),1,16))::bit(64)::bigint)
from x;
```

You can use regexp_split_to_table https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8866ff2fba92d45a9d19ee0fb24168aa

```
with x as (
select 'test1' as word
union all
select 'test2'
union all
select 'test2'
union all
select 'test2'
union all
select 'test1'
union all
select 'test1'
)
select
    x.word,
    (select sum(ascii(regexp_split_to_table)) from regexp_split_to_table(x.word, ''))
from x;
```

Unfortunately it is not unique. It only calculates sum of ascii numbers of given word.